# Find the set of $x>0$ such that the series $\sum\limits_n x^{\ln{n}}$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

> If $x>0$, find the set of all values of $x$ such that series is convergent$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^{\ln{n}}$$

My attempt:- I used Ratio test for finding the set of all values of $x$ such that series is convergent.

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x^{\ln{n+1}}}{x^{\ln{n}}}$$

$$=\lim_{x\to\infty}x^{\ln\frac{n+1}{n}}$$
This quantity must be less than one for getting a convergent series, I am not able to judge. Can you please help me to find the interval of convergence?

Comment: Hint: $x^{\ln n}=n^{\ln x}$.

Comment: The notion of radius of convergence refers to entire series. The function in your question is not an entire series. You might instead, more properly, ask for the set of values of $x>0$ such that the series converges.

Comment: I have edited errors in my question. Please help me to solve.

Comment: @RaviPrakash Huh? Certainly not a duplicate.

Comment: Just to add a refence not related directly with your problem, since $a_n=\log n$ isn't a sequence of integers, but maybe you want to know this nice paper: Csaba Sándor, *A note on a conjecture of Erdös-Turán*, INTEGERS: The Electronical Journal of  Combinatorial Number Theory **8** (1), Article A30 (2008). It is a free access journal. Is not required a response of this comment, and good luck.

Comment: @Ravi Prakash Can you prove ,how this question is equivalent to alternating euler sum ?

Comment: @user243301 ... $\zeta(-\log x)$

Comment: Many thanks @reuns now I've read the calculations in the answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

take $x=e^{-y}$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^{\ln n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}e^{-y\ln n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^y}$$

The last series converges iff $y>1$.

Hence $0<x<\frac{1}{e}$, for which the series converges.

Comment: Why did u made this selection?

Comment: you said $x>0$, and I show $\ln$, so I thought I need to find series which do not contain $\ln$.... so I took $x=e^{-y}$.

Comment: How can I able to say that this is the only interval?

Comment: @N.Maneesh note that $x\to y$ is a bijective transformation. So you can not find any other point.

Comment: can you please give reference to a textbook consist of similar problems. Actually I am preparing a competitive exam in India. I need to practice lot of problems like this . How to learn this type of basic techniques ?  I am weak in this.

Comment: @N.Maneesh I don't know where can you find problem like this... I know this competitive exam you are talking abt (NET) has books like previous year question etc. Again I can not suggest you any specific real analysis book,Rudin is good, but not for beginners... I never really followed any specific real analysis book (jump from one book to another actually), **also**, I studied statistics in your country, so it is not a good idea **to ask me** actually

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63745/discussion-between-n-maneesh-and-manmaid).

Comment: Instead of "Then $y>1$" it would be better to say "The last series converges iff $y>1$."

Comment: @zhw. thank, I just edited.