# Test the series for convergence or divergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Test the series for convergence or divergence

(a)    $$\sum_{n=2}^\infty{1\over{{(\ln n)}^{\ln n}}}$$

(b)    $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty{(\sqrt[n]{2}-1)}$$

and I found out that these two are some what converging but don't know how to reason it.
Please help!!

Now I think I got (b) so Please help with (a)!!!

Comment: For (b), we have $\sqrt[n]2-1\sim\frac{\ln2}n$

Comment: First question. How did you write the first part with the sqrt part?

Comment: @Applepie, Are you sure the first one is convergent?

Answer (score 2):

Use this result,

[Find the set of $x>0$ such that the series $\sum\limits_n x^{\ln{n}}$ converges](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2392088/find-the-set-of-x0-such-that-the-series-sum-limits-n-x-lnn-converges)

$\log n \ge 3 $, $n\ge 21 \implies$
$\frac{1}{\log n} \leq \frac{1}{3}\implies$
$ (\frac{1}{\log n})^{\log n} \leq {\frac{1}{3}}^{\log n}$. So, converges(Since, $ 3 >e$. So,$1/3<1/e)$

Comment: @Applepie please check the link and check whether my reasoning is right or not?

Comment: umm isn't $\log n$ smaller than n? how can it be bigger?

Comment: Yes. sorry! Let me check any other bound.

Comment: @Applepie How is my answer. right now?

Comment: In your case doesn't n just need to be 3? since if you take n as above 3 you have $1\over n$ smaller than 1. If you have n to $\infty$ and if you have number below 1 it goes to 0. And I think it is right!( Well this is what I think... I don't have the answer.... sorry)

Comment: Let me ask to experts.