# Interval of convergence of this particular series: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a^{\ln n}$

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

This question was asked in my real analysis quiz and I couldn't solve it.

> For a>0 , the series$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a^{\ln n}$ is convergent in which largest interval?

The problem is that I am unable to manipulate the $\ln n$ in exponent of a to use ratio test ?

Can you please help me with that ? OR any alternative way to solve it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the set of $x> 0$ such that the series $\sum\limits_n x^{\ln{n}}$ converges](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2392088/find-the-set-of-x0-such-that-the-series-sum-limits-n-x-lnn-converges)

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2519631/42969 – both found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum%20a%5E%7B%5Cln%20n%7D%24)

Comment: Note that this is *not* a power series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite :
$$
a^{\ln n} = (e^{\ln a})^{\ln n} = e ^{\ln a \ln n} = (e^{\ln n})^{\ln a} = n^{\ln a}
$$

so the sum is equivalent to $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{\ln a}$. Have we seen this before?

Answer (score 0):

The ratio test doesn't apply; if you set $a_n=a^{\ln(n)}$ then $$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=a^{\ln(1+1/n)}\rightarrow 1$$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. Notice this series is obviously going to diverge if $a\geq 1$. Now if $a <1$ you can use the integral test; the function $f(x)=a^{\ln(x)}$ is decreasing and positive on $[1,\infty)$ and $\int_1^\infty a^{\ln(x)}dx=\int_0^\infty(ae)^udu$. Can you continue?